# publish message to facebook fan page

Tags: facebook

i want to publish message to my facebook fan page from my web site. any user can write message to me on my website and when click on publish message needs to appear  on my facebook fan page wall is it possible with PHP ??
if so please guide me?

Comment: simply i want to facilitate to any one can post any message to my facebook fan page through the web page.

Comment: When you say "anyone" do you want to publish on their behalf (which means the post on the page wall should be **BY** that user)?

Comment: yes it's just like facebook's wall post text box and pulish button on my web site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook API to post on pages' feeds, just like if they were users.

> The `feed` connection corresponds to the Page's Wall. You can create a
>   link, post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the
>   PAGE_ID/feed connection.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and [.../docs/reference/api/page/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)